# scala.bat run simple scala program in windows 7 64bit

Tags: scala, batch-file, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to run the following scala program in windows 7 64bit

**play2.scala**

```
    println("Hello")
```

When try run it using the following command, the compilation process takes forever:

```
    C:\tmp> scala play2.scala
```

I'm not knowledgeable of batch files but when I comment out the "@echo off" from the scala.bat, this is basically what the script is doing (I changed the paths to **"C:\..."** for clarity) :

```
   "java" -Xmx256M -Xms32M -Dscala.home="C:\..." -Dscala.usejavacp=true -cp "C:\..." scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner  scala.tools.nsc.CompileServer
```

This command is executed over and over by scala.bat and it takes a minute to execute every time.

By the way, when I :load play2.scala from the REPL, it works just fine.

Any advise will be really helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scala.tools.nsc.CompileServer shouldn't even appear anywhere in scala.bat.
You could redownload scala-2.10.3.zip from http://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.10.3.html
and replace the old scala folder.

Also you should set SCALA_HOME e.g. to C:\scala-2.10.3
and JAVA_HOME e.g. to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45 and check your PATH variable to see if you have only one scala/bin folder in there.

Comment: Thank you! Setting SCALA_HOME and JAVA_HOME fixed my problem.